# Can't connect css file to html

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I try to connect my css file to html with php, butt nothing seems to work. I have looked through similar topics but I am unable to find a right answer.

Any help would be appreciated.

my file with header:

```
<html>

   <head>
      <title>BNU Student Web Application</title>
      <!-- styles and JS here -->
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/styles.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   </head>

   <body>
```

and my file structure:

[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEUzL.png)

Comment: It's always best to start with the root directory instead of using relative directories. `/css/styles.css` is most likely what you need.

Comment: I have tried that but it didn't work, styles still dont apply

Comment: Use absolute path or url

Comment: i tried absolute path but its not working

Comment: Figure out the path that you can use to view just the CSS file in your browser, then use that for the absolute path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just `css/styles.css` (without ../../).

Comment: this works for me somehow, I tried the same with /css/styles.css and it didn't. I am just a bit confused because when I place it without / php storm sends shows me an alert and colors the path - Cannot resolve directory 'css'. but styles are applying

Answer (score 0):

An easy way around this, copy all of the css class/stylings from your css file, and paste them in your html file like so:

```
<html>

   <head>
      <title>BNU Student Web Application</title>
      <!-- styles and JS here -->
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/styles.css">-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <style>
          div {
           padding: 0; (this is just an example of a styling)
        }
      </style>
   </head>

   <body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the back slash as given code. because the CSS file you have requested only from index.php so use this following code

```
`<html>

   <head>
      <title>BNU Student Web Application</title>
      <!-- styles and JS here -->
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   </head>

   <body>
```

`